# Android Studio: Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio, hardware-acceleration, amd-processor

This is driving me absolutely crazy and I can't find any help. I'm fairly novice when it comes to emulators, and even more so when it comes to Android Studio. Here's my problem: I installed Android Studio. Downloaded the SDK updates, including the HAXM one, and set up my own AVD. Upon trying to start up my AVD, or even the starter AVD that was already there, I get an error stating that "emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!"

I've done some googling and tried to finish the install of HAXM using the install file in the Android/SDK folder. I was promptly told that the installation failed and that my CPU didn't allow for Intel Hardware Acceleration, or something like that. I read somewhere that the only way I can use Hardware Acceleration on AMD is if I were on Linux, with which I have no experience with. So I tried giving up. Now I can't figure out how to disable Hardware Acceleration entirely in Android Studio. I haven't even begun learning how to write in android because I can't get an AVD up and running.

Does anyone have any tips for a complete Android noob? I thought this would be something fun to try since I was at once point fairly good with C++ and I have always been a huge fan of android. However, I've avoided doing anything GUI related until now, and I'm not finding it very fun at the moment.

I'm running an AMD system with 8GB of ram. More specifically, I'm using an AMD FX-4130 Quad-Core Processor on a GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 Motherboard.

Comment: My recommendation is using Genymotion its a better android emulator that works great

Comment: I'll check that out once I get more into android programming if I keep having problems with Android Studio. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Since you are new to the Android development environment: Android studio does not equal the emulator. AS is basically the editor. And that gives you a shortcut to execute your code on a device, that can be an emulator. It also comes bundeled with some other applications (Android SDK tools) like adb, gradle, device monitor etc. To ask your question about the right module with the right tag will increase your chances of getting a good answer on SO.

Comment: For some reason noone mentioned that you can run your apps on a physical device (i.e. Android phone, tablet etc.) and forget about emulators whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately AMD's virtualization technology AMD-V is not compatible with Intel HAXM. Your only choices are to either get familiar with Linux or use a ARM-based AVD, which doesn't require virtualization.

You can find instructions for Linux on Android Developers' document on [Using the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm).

Comment: Awesome solution for a desperate noob! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Genymotion instead of default one. Its faster than the default one. And this emulator is compatible with both Intel and AMD. Genymotion just uses Virtualbox to run Android in VM.

Here's a link to [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) .
Genymotion , [Genymotion user guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)

it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take an android phone with its USB cord then follow these steps:
 
1. plug in phone to computer.

 2. on the phone goto: settings>about device scroll to find build number
 
3. press build number 7x (this enables developer mode)
 
4. go back to settings press developers options select usb debugging, include bug reports, verify apps via usb, and GPU force rendering.
 
5. Check for device connection on the computer 
 
6. add in build.gradle under "buildTypes{" write this

```
debug {  debuggable true  }
```

then when you run your project you should be able to see your phone in the avd selection then select it. Your phone will awaken automatically with your application running except it will be a little semi-efficient boot process.
Also do not forget to remove the debug code from your gradle file when you app is finished.

Comment: It is necessary to set ```debuggable``` ? I'm using a hardware device without this option.